# Async server or quickly loading state in R

Tags: r

I’m writing a webserver that sometimes has to pass data through a R script.

Unfortunately startup is slow, since i have to load some libraries which load other libraries etc.

Is there a way to either

- load libraries, save the interpreter state to a file, and load that state fast when invoked next time? Or
- maintain a background R process that can be sent messages (not just lowlevel data streams), which are delegated to asynchronous workers (i.e. sending a new message before the previous is parsed shouldn’t block)

[R-Websockets](http://illposed.net/websockets.html) is unfortunately synchronous.

Comment: have you looked at `opencpu`? <https://public.opencpu.org/api.html> and <https://public.opencpu.org/jslib.html>

Comment: i’ll look at it. thanks to the “cloud to butt” addon, its homepage looks very promising: “Scientific computing in my butt”

Comment: @Troy sorry, this doesn’t seem to do what i want. it seems to be a REST interface, but i just need to invoke R from server software running on the same machine. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: OK but you can persist objects in the opencpu session (to keep state) - then the next time you call them by objectID (e.g. on localhost) you don't need to go through the computation and load overhead. But not sure if that was what you were after?

Comment: [Rserve](http://rforge.net/Rserve/) and [FastRWeb](http://rforge.net/FastRWeb/) might be helpful.

Comment: @Troy can you also persist loaded liraies? because that’s phat i’m after: skipping the library loading step.

Comment: @MartinMorgan Seems to be all synchronous: it opens a connection to a R process and evals code there, but once the process is busy calculating something, it can’t handle more commands.

Comment: I think the design is to manage multiple Rserve instances either through robust web server software or through [RSclient](http://www.rforge.net/RSclient/index.html) (e.g., the RS.collect help page). Rserve is persistent so at least addresses your slow startup time.

Comment: maybe a combination of Rserve and fork, so that the Rserve becomes available instantaneously

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rserve and RSclient is an easy way to do create and use an Async server.

Open two R sessions.

in the first one type:

```
require(Rserve)
run.Rserve(port=6311L)
```

in the second one type:

```
require(RSclient)
rsc = RS.connect(port=6311L)
# start with a synchronous call
RS.eval(rsc, {x <<- vector(mode="integer")}, wait=TRUE)
# continue with an asynchronous call
RS.eval(rsc, {cat("begin")
              for (i in 1:100000) x[[i]] <-i
              cat("end")
              TRUE
        }, 
        wait=FALSE)
# call collect until the result is available
RS.collect(rsc, timeout=1)
```